# Return a string value from C# to c++

Tags: c#, c++, com

How to pass the string from C# to COM C++ ? I have done for int and it is working fine.

My COM C++ code for int return type:

```
void ServiceAdapter::GetErrorCode1234()
{
long x;
m_server->GetErrorCodeOnLoginFailure(&x);
//So I get my return code value in x;
}
```

My C# code for int return type:
So from C# iam calling like this:

```
int GetErrorCodeOnLoginFailure()
{
 return 3 //some return code
}
```

But if I do the same for String return , the code is getting crashed at run time.

My COM C++ code for string return type:

```
BSTR ServiceAdapter::GetVersion1234()
{
BSTR x = :SysAllocString(CCTIUtils:stringToBSTR(L""));
m_server->GetAdapterVersion(&x); // The code is crashing here.
return x;
}
```

My C# code for string return type:

> string GetAdapterVersion() { return "6.4.23"; }

What is the issue?

Comment: Your call to GetAdapterVersion returns a string rather than taking it as a reference parameter. Are you sure that call is right?

Comment: Yeah. That's how it works. Its working fine for int

Comment: std::wstring ServiceAdapter::GetVersion1234(),

Why std::wstring? It should be BSTR, isn't it?

Comment: I changed to BSTR ..but still its not working. I think , the issue is something to do with Allocation of memory to x

Comment: Question Do you have to use wchar_t* and convert it to char* inside the dll. ?? just curious

Answer (score 0):

Will this example work for you..? if not Sunil.. then I don't know how to consult on this issue

You need to pass the string by reference so the C# code gets an updated string:

```
int GetString(String^% ValueData)
```

or better yet:

```
String^ GetString() 
{
    char buffer[666];  // Hmya, what to pick?
    unmanagedGetString(buffer);
    return System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)buffer);
}
```